# Flexslider doesn't recognise dynamically loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, flexslider

I am using the SoundCloud API to load artwork into the HTML document as an `ul` via Javascript, using [instructions I found here](http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/docs/application.html), then slide through a carousel of the covers (wrapped in `li` tags) using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). This works fine when the the list items are hard-coded into the HTML document, however, when I use the loading script to dynamically retrieve the the artwork as an `img` from the API and inject them into the DOM, Flexslider does not register that they are there and add the necessary styling to the `li`s, despite the Flexslider script being loaded after the SoundCloud script. Can anyone show me how to make Flexslider pick up on the dynamic content? Here are my files:

#### HTML (snippet)

```
<div class="page-container">
    <section id="work">
        <h3>Work</h3>
        <p>Check out my latest mixes below.</p>
        <div class="sc-stream">
            <ul class="cover-flow clearfix">
                <!-- Covers inject here -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <hr>
</div><!-- End page-container -->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/vendor/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script src="js/sc-custom-player.js"></script>

<script src="js/flexslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

#### sc-custom-player.js

Same as the [file found here](http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/js/application.js)

#### main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.sc-stream').flexslider({
        namespace:  "sc-",
        animation:  "slide",
        selector:   ".cover-flow > li",
        slideshow:  false,
        controlNav: false,
        minItems:   1,
        itemWidth:  224,
        itemMargin: 8
    });

});
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It might be that you need a slight delay to allow the data to fully load first? Using setTimeout worked on my current project:

HTML

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

function initGame() {
    // load xml data file (from same domain)
    // iterate xml elements and load <li>s into HTML variable

    $(HTML).appendTo('.slides');

    setTimeout(function () {
        startGame();
    }, 500);
}

function startGame() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        randomize: true,
        directionNav: false,
        touch: true,
        after: function (slider) {
            $(".flex-control-nav li").removeClass("active");
            $(".flex-active").parent().addClass("active");
        },
        itemMargin: 5
    });
}

initGame();

});
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back, I've been working the past few days. However, I've just added `setTimeout` to the script and it is working a treat! I did add this elsewhere, but the combination of your answer and @Wolf's has finally cracked it. Thanks!

Comment: Great news; happy you're back in business!

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have written the `flexslider` code in `$(document).ready` function

You have to write the following code after loading the content dynamically

```
$('.sc-stream').flexslider({
    namespace:  "sc-",
    animation:  "slide",
    selector:   ".cover-flow > li",
    slideshow:  false,
    controlNav: false,
    minItems:   1,
    itemWidth:  224,
    itemMargin: 8
});
```

Comment: Still not happening. I tried adding it after the content load on line 45 of sc-custom-player.js, but that only loads one of the artworks, albeit correctly. If I move it down it doesn't recognise anything again. Can you be more specific e.g. where *exactly* in the file?

Comment: Add it after `$.each(playlist.tracks, function(index, track)` loop is closed. ie after line number 95 in the attached sc-custom-player.js file.

Comment: Thank-you very much. I combined your answer with the `setTimeout` solution below and it is now showing just great. Considering both of you provided helpful comments, I am not going to mark either as correct, but I have provided acknowledgement in the form of a vote-up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

```
function CreateBrandsGallery() {
  $.getJSON("services/products/read.php?req=brands", function(data) {
    $.each(data.product_brand, function(i,data) {
      var box = "<li class='add-bord-left'>";
      box += "<div class='brand_carousel_box_img remove-over add-bord-radius fl_left'><a class='item_detail_box' href='products.php?req=allproducts&art="+data.brand_id+"'>";
      box += "<img src='"+data.brand_preview+"' />";
      box += "</a></div>";
      box += "</li>"
      $(box).appendTo('div.brands_gallery ul');
      setTimeout(function () { ProductSBrandsGallerySlider(); }, 500);
    });
  });   
}
```

And the other function:

```
function ProductSBrandsGallerySlider() {
  $('.brands_gallery,.products_new_gallery').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    reverse: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,
    animationSpeed: 500, 
    itemWidth: 233,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: 4,
    maxItems: 4,
    randomize: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    initDelay: 300
  });
}
```